# Update Windows 2000 server standard to Windows 2000 server professional with AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2000

I have a Windows 2000 Server Standard Edition server (that's right, standard) on a *home* network  with three systems doing basic file/print sharing (and a few other services).  Until recently the systems were running XP Home, but I now have them updated to either XP Pro or Vista Ultimate.  I also have a Server 2000 Advanced product key + license that I acquired at the same time as the Standard license.

Now that every machine on the network will support being joined to a domain I would like to update the server to Advanced with Active Directory.  Can I do this in place, or do I need to re-install from scratch?  What do I need to know to get Active Directory set up?

Comment: ... windows 2000?

Comment: Yes, 2000.  My 2000 licenses are legal, but I'm not in a position to pay for 2003 (or a computer that will run it).  It's this or switch to a linux-based server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no advantage to running Windows 2000 Server Advanced unless you have a lot of cpus / cores or a lot of ram. Windows 2000 Server Standard will run Active Directory. My guess is your current install utilizes all your hardware fine.

Run dcpromo to install Active Directory.

I would also say that Active Directory is probably overkill on a 4 computer network.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 2000 Professional is the desktop edition, not server.  Are you talking about Windows 2000 Advanced Server?  You can run dcpromo on the server to install AD and make it a domain controller.

Comment: D'oh!  Yes, that should read 'Advanced'.  Can I do that to the current standard install?

Comment: Ok.  Alas, no.  There is no upgrade path from Win2000 Standard to Win2000 Advanced server.  Here are the options: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q232039.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, AD is overkill for a home network, especially if you need to linger on Windows 2000 to do it.  If you don't want to shell out, why not try out a Gnu/Linux distro?  One with lots of users (eg Ubuntu or Fedora) is likely to have more documentation or help available out there for setting up any given use case.